# how to set press value simultaneously?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I set press value in onkeyevent function. But value by default false and It's press then set press value is true. I created two button in one screen and I set Button value to maintain Focus Correctly. I set active value true and open dialog box and maintain focus with dialog button but Its set to dialog button and screen button both the focus work together. Does anyone know how to separate the Both Press?

Here my code to set both the value

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean

  ? "PanelSet :: Key Event is about to execute - key = "key " press = " press 
  '  getConfig()

'  ? "Display the XML Data: "m.gridpanel.grid.content.getChild(m.gridpanel.grid.itemFocused)
  handled = false


   ? "here the focus available dialog focus "
     if press = true then

      if m.keyid.active = true and key = "OK" then
        ?"Email Ok Press"

                showdialogid()   
                handled = true

      else if m.keypass.active = true and key = "OK" then
        ?"Password Ok Press"

                showdialogpass()
                handled = true 

      end if
      return handled 

    end if

    if press = false then
    ? "here Login Screen Press available " press
      ' here the every time call if condition if enter the value on keyboard and keybord ok press to call textbox password active = true

            if key = "up" or key = "down"

                if key = "down"
                    ?"here down key"

                    if m.keypass.active = true 

                        m.keyid.active = false
                        m.keypass.active = false
                        m.btnsubmit.setFocus(true)
                        m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/newsignin.png"
                        m.btnsubmit.iconUri=""
                        m.btnsubmit.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
                        handled = true

                    else if m.keyid.active = true

                        m.keyid.active = false
                        m.keypass.active = true
                        handled = true

                    else if m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri <> "" 

                        ? "setting active and key down press " 
                        m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri = "" 
                        m.btnsubmit.setFocus(false)
                        m.btnsetting.setFocus(true)
                        m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/newsetting.png"
                        m.btnsetting.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
                        handled = true

                    else if m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri <> ""

                       ? "id active and key down press"
                       m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri = ""
                       m.btnsetting.setFocus(false)
                       m.keyid.setFocus(true)
                       m.keyid.active = true
                       handled  = true

                        handled = true   
                    end if
                    handled = true

                else if key = "up"

                    ? "here up key"
                    if m.keypass.active = true 

                        ?"id active and press up"
                        m.keypass.active = false
                        m.keyid.active = true
                        handled = true

                    else if m.keyid.active = true 

                        ?"setting active and press up"

                        m.keyid.active = false
                        m.btnsetting.setFocus(true)
                        m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/newsetting.png"
                        m.btnsetting.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
                        handled = true

                    else if m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri <> "" 
                         ?"submit active and press up"

                         m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri = ""
                         m.btnsetting.setFocus(false)
                         m.btnsubmit.setFocus(true)
                         m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/newsignin.png"
                         m.btnsubmit.iconUri=""
                         m.btnsubmit.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
                         handled = true

                    else if m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri <> "" 

                        ? "pass active and press up"                         
                        'press = false
                        ? "press value active : " press 
                        m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri = ""
                        m.btnsubmit.setFocus(false)
                        m.keypass.setFocus(true)
                        m.keypass.active = true
                        handled = true
                    end if
                    handled = true
                end if
                handled = true
            end if


       if key = "OK" and m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri <> ""

        ?"Click the sign in button"

         handled = true

       else if key = "OK" and m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri <> ""

        handled = true

      end if 

   return handled
   end if


  if press = true then

           ? "Video size incresed"

'Key handler for ok button press then store the url in xml file and use everywhere particular url


   if key="options" then
           'we are not in video playback

'            If Not m.video.visible Then

                if NOT m.dialog.visible then

                    ? "video option menu is open"
'                   ShowKeyboardScreen()
                     showdialog()
                     m.dialog.visible = false
                     m.dialog.focusable = false
'                    if m.dialog.visible = true

'                            m.dialog.visible = false ' Here the close the keyboard dialog box

'                    end if

'Here the Code For the if ok button Press then dialog box close and load the channel
                    result = true
                    return true

                else

                    ? "video option menu is closed"

                    m.dialog.visible = false 
                    m.dialog.setFocus(false)
                    m.top.videoplayer.setfocus = true
                    m.gridpanel.grid.content.setFocus = true
                    m.listpanel.list.content.setFocus = true
                    m.focusedNode.SetFocus(true)
                    result = true
                    return true  
                end if
            end if

    if key = "back"
      ? "Back pressed - nikunj = handled = " handled
  if  not m.video.state = "playing" then

      handled = verifyexit()

      ? "Back pressed - jigar = handled = " handled

      return handled'true
  end if                        
            handled = false  
            'video = m.top.videoPlayer.findNode("liveVideo")

            ? "Video state = " m.video.state

            if (m.video.state = "playing")
                ?"set videoplayer focus"
                m.video.control = "stop"
 '               m.ButtonGroup.setFocus(true)
                m.video.visible = false
                m.top.videoPlayer.visible = false
                m.top.visible = true
                m.top.setFocus(true)
                m.panelset.setFocus(true)
                m.gridpanel.setFocus(true)
                handled = true

            end if
        'handled = true
        return handled
    end if  

    if key = "play"

                 list = []
                     color = "#80000000" 'semi-transparent black


                   ' m.video.control = "pause"

                    if m.video.state = "playing"
                    ? "video is paused"
                     'Here the paused label print on above video 
                     list.Push({
                          Text: "Paused"
                          TextAttrs: { font: "huge" }
                          TargetRect: m.top.videoPlayer.Resolution

                    })

                    m.video.control = "pause"   

                     m.top.visible = true
                    else
                    ? "video is resumed"     

                          m.video.control = "resume"

                          list.Push({
                          Text: "Paused"
                          TextAttrs: { font: "huge" }
                          TargetRect: m.top.videoPlayer.Resolution

                    })
                    end if

                ' m.canvas.SetLayer(1, list)                       
       end if
     m.progress = 0

  m.position = 60
 if key = "fastforward"

    ? "video fast forward"

     m.video.control = "FastForward"
     m.position = m.position + 60

 end if
 if key = "rewind"

 ? "video Rewind"

     m.video.control = "Rewind"
     m.position = m.position - 60

 end if

     if key = "replay"

     m.gridpanel.visible = false
     m.listpanel.visible = false

     m.keypanel.setFocus(true)
    return true           
     end if

    if key = "up" or key = "down"

        ? "Up key is change the video channel and down key for again particular video displayed"

        bUp = true
        if key = "down" then
            bUp = false
        end if

        if (m.video.state = "playing")
            ?"set videoplayer focus"
            m.video.control = "stop"

            m.gridpanel.setFocus(true)
            ?" m.gridpanel.content.getChildCount() = " m.gridpanel.grid.content.getChildCount()

            nTotalItem = m.gridpanel.grid.content.getChildCount()

             ? " m.gridpanel.grid.itemFocused = " m.gridpanel.grid.itemFocused
             if key = "up"
                 if m.gridpanel.grid.itemFocused = 0 then
                     m.gridpanel.grid.jumpToItem = nTotalItem - 1
                     ? "arrow selected "
                 else
                     m.gridpanel.grid.jumpToItem = m.gridpanel.grid.itemFocused - 1
                     ? "arrow selected "
                 end if
             endif

             if key = "down"

                 if m.gridpanel.grid.itemFocused = nTotalItem - 1 then
                     m.gridpanel.grid.jumpToItem = 0
                     ? "arrow selected "
                 else
                     m.gridpanel.grid.jumpToItem = m.gridpanel.grid.itemFocused + 1
                     ? "arrow selected "
                 end if
             endif

            ? " m.gridpanel.grid.itemFocused = " m.gridpanel.grid.itemFocused

            m.video.control = "Play"

            m.top.videoPlayer.setFocus(true) 

            handled = true            

        end if     
    end if

  end if

  return handled
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are coding for keypress = false. Most probably this will be the cause of your issue. Don't know what are your requirements, but its not a good practice to program on false 'keypress' events as 'false' events are generated when key is released. As per my observation for your code, I have some suggestions--

Set `handled = false` as first line of *onKeyEvent()* function

Add `return handled` as the last statement of *onKeyEvent()* function

Check if this solves your problem.

Comment: Now I put all function in my code I press ok key and move to dialiog then press down key to both value should be display dialog and behind textbox.